# Phonegap / Cordova Export to CSV(or) Excel Programmatically

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developing a Phonegap Android application where I need to export data from the db to an Excel or CSV. And I want to read the data from an Excel or CSV file into my application.

Is there any plugin to achieve this? Any idea or suggestion to acheive this?

Comment: How does you DB look like?

Comment: It is quite complex with mixture of foreign keys and references .. so i want to export it to an csv after processing it in my js .

Answer (score 0):

Use ordinary HTML file upload or Try JavaScript FormData()

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// POST to httpbin which returns the POST data as JSON
request.open('POST', 'submitform.php', /* async = */ false);

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('appendedFile', new Blob(['bar']),{type : 'text/text'} 'bar.txt'); // try to write Excel File here

request.send(formData);
```

For more help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Nope i don't need this type of code .. I want to export the db table into the phone storage itself

Comment: Web service is a proper way to get data from db with your condition. If you need to use CSV file in phonegap try http://papaparse.com/  I got that link from Google.

Answer (score 0):

I think the plugin you want is the Cordova File plugin:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Also if you're using AngularJS, there's an ngCordova wrapper for the Cordova plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

I would give an example but those contain great documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know in what lang is your app developed, but if you are using AngularJs, I recently did an app that exports calculated data into csv, and then I email it using base64 format to the email. Ifyou are using angular, check ngCSV https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv

davor